# long mode 1GB paging

Tags: assembly, x86-64, paging

i want to use 1GB pages in long mode because 4KB/2MB make things more complicated then i need. so i just copied the example from OSDev: 
https://wiki.osdev.org/Entering_Long_Mode_Directly

and this worked fine with VirtualBox. then i tried to do as written  in 
AMD64 Manual, Volume 2, Page 137:
https://support.amd.com/TechDocs/24593.pdf  with 2 paging tables

(and yes, i´ve checked cpuid 8000_0001h /EDX bit 26)

```
%define PAGE_PRESENT    (1 << 0)
%define PAGE_WRITE      (1 << 1)
%define PS_BIT      (1<<7)
;1GB Pages avec 2 tables
; Build the Page Map Level 4.
; di points to the Page Map Level 4 table.
lea eax, [di + 0x1000]         ; Put the address of the Page Directory Pointer Table in to EAX.
or eax, PAGE_PRESENT | PAGE_WRITE ; Or EAX with the flags - present flag, writable flag.
mov [di], eax                  ; Store the value of EAX as the first PML4E.

lea di, [di + 0x1000]             
mov eax, PAGE_PRESENT | PAGE_WRITE | PS_BIT    ; Move the flags into EAX - and point it to 0x0000.
mov ebx,0
mov ecx,512

; Build the Page Table.
.LoopPageTable:
mov [di], eax
add di,2
mov [di],ebx
add ebx,2^14 ;so this adds 1GB(2^30) to the table entry
add di, 6
loop .LoopPageTable

;continue Enter long mode.
```

but now VirtualBox crashes.

i hope someone can help me here :) 
waiting.

Comment: If VirtualBox itself crashes, that's a bug in VirtualBox.  The guest shouldn't be able to crash the VM manager, only lock up the virtual machine.  Did you try a different VM, or an emulator with a built-in debugger like BOCHS?

Comment: `or eax, PAGE_PRESENT | PAGE_WRITE` makes no sense there.  `EAX` holds an address, so you're modifying the pointer.  Did you mean `or dword [eax], PAGE_PRESENT | PAGE_WRITE`?  Also, are you in 32-bit protected mode at this point?  If so, why are you using 16-bit addressing modes like `[di]`?  If not, why are you setting ECX, when `loop` will default to only using CX in 16-bit mode, unless you use an address-size prefix on `loop`.  (Or really, why use `loop` at all, it's slow.  Also, why increment the pointer by only 2 bytes when you're storing 4-byte EAX?

Comment: ok 1. i´m in protected mode 2. [di] says that i want to store the value of eax there 3. the pointer in the loop at first just stores the PAGE_PRESENT, PAGE_WRITE and PS_BIT and then i needed a way to store a value bigger than 2^32 so i thought: 1GB=2^30=2^14+2^16 so probably that´s wrong...

Comment: i won´t sound rude it´s just that i don´t see a difference between using [E]DI or [E]CX. just in addition: i found at the CR3 describtion that the lower bits of the CR3 are assumed to be Zeroes and are part of the address for PML4 but the page entries... do they work the same way?-no sure at all-

Comment: That’s pretty ingenious, storing ebx to the PDPTE with an offset of 2, so you don’t need to do 64-bit arithmetic. I wouldn’t have thought of that. But each PDPTE (and PML4E) is 8 bytes, so you’re only writing part of each entry. Are you sure the memory is zero before you start?

Comment: @Peter, the way page tables are constructed, each page table entry consists of a pointer with certain control bits set in the low 12 bits, so that part of his code actually looks okay.

Comment: Are you sure the syntax 2^14 does what you expect in your assembler? In some assemblers, ^ means xor.

Comment: @prl: oh right.  I guess it makes sense to put the next level page tables 0x1000 bytes after the data you're about to store, so that LEA result really is data.  16-bit addressing modes are still a very weird choice for protected mode, and so is leaving 2 bytes unwritten after `mov [di],ebx` and `add di,6`.  But doing overlapping stores after `mov [di],eax` / `add [di],2` apparently just saves an operand-size prefix vs. `mov [di], ax`.

Comment: @PeterCordes : This page table code is running in real mode.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Ok I give up.  The OP commented earlier "1. i´m in protected mode", so I believed them.

Comment: @PeterCordes The OP is wrong ;-). If you review the OSDev code he linked you'd see the modifcation of CR0, the jump into long mode, and setting up of the GDT happens after the page table creation code. There is a real mode boot sector at the bottom that uses the long mode file at the top of the tutorial page.

Comment: the link... i tried but it failed /triple fault (and the OSDev forum is 12 years old - all links dead). so i first enter protected mode and then doing this stuff

Comment: In your question you said "so i just copied the example from OSDev: https://wiki.osdev.org/Entering_Long_Mode_Directlyand this worked fine with VirtualBox".You said the code worked in VirtualBox but now your comment says "the link... i tried but it failed /triple fault (and the OSDev forum is 12 years old - all links dead)" . So did the original OSDev code work or didn't it?

Comment: I took the exact OSDev code and set it up exactly as they did and ran it per the instructions in QEMU and it worked and printed `Hello World!` with white on blue characters. I then created a floppy disk image by doing `dd if=/dev/zero of=disk.img bs=1024 count=1440` and then `dd if=LongModeDirectly of=disk.img conv=notrunc` . I ran that floppy image `disk.img` in virtualbox and it worked as well.

Comment: The real problem is that you only show a portion of your code(the page table stuff) so this isn't an [mcve] . If you showed us your entire bootloader it might be clearer exactly what you are doing and why it might fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well prl was right. i´ve replaced 2^14 through 16384 and was able to do a jmp into 64 bit code. thank you very much

also Peter was right, VirtualBox then crashes at

```
[BITS 64]      
LongMode:
mov ax, DATA_SEG
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
mov fs, ax
mov gs, ax
mov ss, ax

; Blank out the screen to a blue color.
mov edi, 0xB8000
mov rcx, 500                      ; 500=80*25*2/8
mov rax, 0x1F201F201F201F20       ; Set the value to set the screen to: Blue background, white foreground, blank spaces.
```

*when trying "rep stosq" it crashes*

```
rep stosq  
hlt
```

©osdev.org

i don´t know why but when using my computer it works (copy bytecode to usb and restart)

so thx for your time this is solved.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: `1<<14` you mean, for 2 to the power 14.  (Because `2` to the 0th power = 1).

Comment: You can do 2 to the power of a value by shifting the value1 to the left .This should work as well and is clearer `add ebx,1<<14`